# Inverse probability censor weighting in lifelines Cox Proportional Hazard fit

Tags: cox-model, lifelines

I am trying to apply inverse probability censor weights to my cox proportional hazard model that I've implemented in the lifelines python package and I'm running into some basic confusion on my part on how to use the API.  The goal of the exercise is to determine the mortality curves for untreated patients from observed data that includes treatment.  I've created a simulated dataset to explore the problem.  I've taken my data which is naturally in a one-row-per-patient format, and broken it into one row per patient per month active.  I used that data and the pooled logits method to come up with inverse probability censor weights (IPCW).  I know these weights are good, because when I apply them to a Kaplan Meir fit of the data, they reweight the observed mortality (shown below in gray) to obtain weighted mortality (shown in blue) and that matches the true mortality (shown in green).

Below is the code for the Kaplan Meir fit:

```
kmf = KaplanMeierFitter()
kmf.fit(pdf_monthly_stratified['t_leave'],
         event_observed=pdf_monthly_stratified['death_event_observed'],
         entry=pdf_monthly_stratified['t_enter'],
         weights=pdf_monthly_stratified['ipcw_pl'])
```

What is not clear to me, however, is how to apply the weights to my coxph fit.  In fact I have multiple weights per patient for each of the timepoints.  One way I tried was weighting each patient month separately and treating the patient as if each month was a separate patient entering and leaving the dataset on that month (see below).  This is more or less what I did with the Kaplan Meir fit (as shown above) and that worked, but it doesn't work for the CPH fit as shown by the purple line in the graph.  I've also tried weighting the whole patient by the file IPCW weight but that also didn't work.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
pdf_data = pdf_data [['id','DiseaseSeverityPrediction','normalized_age','t_enter','t_leave','death_event_observed','ipcw_pl']]
weighted_cph = CoxPHFitter().fit(pdf_data,
        duration_col = 't_leave',
        event_col='death_event_observed',
        entry_col='t_enter',
        weights_col='ipcw_pl',
       cluster_col  = 'id' )

# Test the model by running it over all patients in population graphed
pdf_progression_subset = pdf_data.loc[pdf_data['DiseaseSeverityPrediction'] >=.5]
pdf_fast_progress_death_mean = weighted_cph.predict_survival_function(pdf_progression_subset,times_lifelines).T.apply(lambda x: 1 - x).mean(0)
```

[image: IPCW Mortality Chart]

Comment: If you drop _all_ covariates from the Cox model, does it still look off to you?

Comment: Have you tried without the ‘id’ for clustering? I recall a paper written by T. Therneau stating that counting process estimation can be performed without accounting for clustering. In your IPCW setup, you are creating multiple observations per ‘id’ at each time point, which may cause some issue with how the Extended Cox model works.

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon I tried it without covariates and the curve looked the same.  What does that mean?  (Todd D, I also tried a separate experiment with covariates and without id and it was still the same.)

Comment: The ID will only effect std. errors, not the survival curve. @Mike can you provide the entire script, including generation of simulated data?

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon, I emailed the source code directly to you separately.  The same data seems to work the following r language coxph model: `cox_monthly_weighted_fit <- coxph(Surv(t_enter, t_leave,
death_event_observed)~DiseaseSeverityPrediction, data = df_sim_monthly,
cluster=id, weight=ipcw_pl, model=TRUE)`